# Access SQL, importing txt files, delimitation

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question regarding Access queries. The below query will import data from a txt file into a new table.  I have tested it, and it delimits by comma. Is there any way to change the delimitation character?

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable
FROM [Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;Database=C:\Docs].Test.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to change the delimitation character?

Yes. You can use a [schema.ini](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(VS.85).aspx) file:

"When the Text driver is used, the format of the text file is determined by using a schema information file. The schema information file is always named Schema.ini and always kept in the same directory as the text data source. The schema information file provides the IISAM with information about the general format of the file, the column name and data type information, and several other data characteristics."

For the complete story see

[Schema.ini File (Text File Driver)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  This would be very useful

Comment: @cam503: can't you do a bit of searching by yourself, once you get a nice and useful direction ?